# Having a set of non unique Key-Value pairs, how can I optimally find a lowest sum subset if distinct keys?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, combinatorics

I understand that the title might be confusing so I'll lead with an example.

I have the following set (actually a map):

```
{
  "ab": 2,
  "ac": 1,
  "ad": 3,
  "ae": 4,
  "abc": 6,
  "b": 2,
  "ba": 4,
  "bc": 4,
  "bd": 3,
  "bde": 4,
  "c": 2,
  "cb": 3,
  "cde": 5,
  "d": 4,
  "e": 4
}
```

I want to find a subset of entries whose keys *uniquely* cover $a,b,c,d,e$ **and** with the minimum sum of the values of the selected entries. *Uniquely* means that each letter in the key should appear in **only one selected entry**.

Some valid subsets:

```
["ab","cde"] -> 7
["ac","bde"] -> 5
["ad","cb","e"] -> 10
["ba","cde"] -> 9
["abc","d","e"] -> 14
```

Some invalid subsets:

```
["ab","ba","cde"]
["ad","bde"]
["abc","cde"]
```

Desired subset:

```
["ac","bde"] -> 5
```

I know I can iterate through the list in nested loops but the complexity becomes $O(n^c)$ where $n$ the total amount of entries and $c$ the amount of entries in the subset (e.g. 2 or 3). For my use case I might have $n=300, c=10$ which becomes prohibitive, even if polynomial (c is a predetermined constant).

Is this a type of problem that can be reduced to a known problem? Do optimizations exist? It is **not** mandatory to select the entries with the minimum value, low value combinations in general are acceptable to me. In the example above, I'd be ok with the entries with sum 5 or 7.

Comment: As an answer points out the general case is NP-hard. You can however, given the constraints solve this in $O(n2^s)$ using dynamic programming.

Comment: @plshelp Can you point to a resource that outlines such a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If $s$ is part of the input then it is NP-hard even to just decide whether a feasible solution exists since this is the [Exact Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem.

You can design an algorithm having time complexity $O(n m 2^\frac{n}{2} )$ by using the split and list technique, where $m$ is the size of the universe.

The idea is as follows:

- Partiion the $n$ possible keys into two sets  $A,B$ of roughly $n/2$ keys each.
- Generate all $O(2^{n/2})$ subsets of $B$ and, for each subset $X$ that covers each element at most once,
  compute a pair $(1_X, w_X)$  where $1_X$ is the characteristic vector of the elements covered by $X$ (w.r.t. the universe) and $w_B$ is the sum of the values of the keys in $X$.
- Collected the pairs generated from $B$ into an array $L$ and sort $L$ (in lexicographic order) in time $O(m |B| \log |B|) = O(n m 2^\frac{n}{2})$.
- Generate all $O(2^{n/2})$ subsets of $A$ and, for each subset $X$ that covers each element at most once, consider the complement $\overline{1}_X$ of its characteristic vector $1_X$ and its "cost" $w_X$. Binary search $L$ for the pair $(\overline{1}_X, w)$ minimizing $w$ (if any). This requires time $O(m \log |B|) = O(m n)$. If such a pair exists, the keys in $X$ and in the set that generated $(\overline{1}_X, w)$ form a candidate solution of overall cost $w_X + w$.
- Return the candidate solution of minimum cost.

Comment: I took a look at the exact cover problem and although it indeed is essentially the same, the difference is that I don't have to make a decision on whether there is exact coverage, I *know* there is (my data is generated in such a way). The goal is to select from one of the the exactly covered subsets the one with the lowest sum. Also for my numbers the time complexity you provide ($O(nm2^\frac{n}{2})$) is larger than $O(n^c)$, right?

Comment: Even if you guaranteed that a solution exists, your problem problem remains hard since you can take an input exact-cover instance and and artificially add a costly solution. Then there will be a cheap solution of the instance of your problem if and only if the original exact-cover instance was a "yes" instance. Once you fix the parameters $n$ and $c$  (and hence $m$), both time complexities simply become $O(1)$. If you fix only $c$, then $O(n^c)$ is better than $O(nm2^{\frac{n}{2}})$ for sufficiently large values of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints it looks like a typical "bitmask" problem.
We can model sets with small sizes such as 10 bits simply as int32.
If the int32 $s$ represents a set we say:

- $s$ contains $i$ if the $i$-th bit of $s$ is $1$ (`s & (i << 1) > 0`)
- $s$ is empty if $s = 0$
- $a$ is a subset of $s$ if `a & s == a`
- union of $b$ and $s$ is `b | s`

Let $n,c$ be as defined in your task.
Using this you could write the following algorithm:

```
dp := integer array of length 2^c initialized to -1
dp[0] = 0
for i = 0...n-1:
    key,val := the i-th key value pair
    s = 0
    for char in key:
        s = s | (1 << char2num(char))
    if dp[s] == -1: dp[s] = val
    dp[s] = min(dp[s], val)
    for j = 0...2^c-1:     #iterate through all bitsets
        union = s | j      #union of two bitsets through OR
        if dp[j] == -1: 
            continue
        if dp[union] == -1: 
            dp[union] = dp[j] + dp[s]
        dp[union] = min(dp[union], dp[j] + dp[s])
answer is dp[2^c-1]
```

`char2num` is just supposed to translate "a" to $0$ "b" to $1$ and so on.
The whole "trick" is to use a dp-array over all sets and use the sets as indices. Furthermore since we use int32, union just becomes an OR operation.